# How to create a mesh attribute containing an image?

Tags: mesh, shader-nodes, custom-attributes

I have a material that mixes two shader nodes together using a mask texture. Pretty simple stuff. However, a difficulty arises when I want to use this material on multiple objects. Either they all have to share the same mask (reducing versatility), or I need to duplicate the material for every object (increasing scene complexity).

Materials can, however, access certain mesh attributes by their names (UV maps, vertex colors, etc.) to achieve results that are different for every object the material is assigned to. For example, using vertex colors as the mask allows the same material to be used on multiple objects while having a unique mask for each. This is useful, but highly dependent on the density of the mesh.

Is there a way to use this same principle for image textures? Creating a mesh attribute of sorts named, for example, "Material_1_Mask" that can, for every mesh datablock, contain a unique image texture; then using that attribute in the material to control the mask on an object-by-object basis?

*TL;DR:* The question is: can I create a custom mesh attribute that contains an image texture rather than a float or integer or some other value, one that can then be used in a shader?
If not, is there another way to achieve the functionality described above?

Answer (score 0):

Mesh attributes contain vertex, edge, face and loop data, so I think the only way to achieve what you want is to wrap each texture in a separate material and store the material on the mesh:

[image]

In order to have a single material, you could make a texture atlas and offset the UV of each object to the positions of the textures in the texture atlas.